# How Can I manual pass information to the register controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

To create a user without the end-user having to type in the details.

Something akin to

```
User::classcreate([
'email' => $email,
'password' => $rand_pass,
.....
]);
```

Thanks for the ideas and feedback in advance :)

The use case is.
The end-user invites another user to use the service by typing in their email and it creates a user with a random password before sending a email to the new user with their created details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there with your code. It should look like this:

```
User::create([
'email' => $email,
'password' => bcrypt($rand_pass),
]);
```

But if you want to hash the password, you should also send the password to that user through email (which is not very secure). When the users logs in for the first time, you should at least require him to change the password.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **create()** method of your **User** model:

```
$userData = [
  'email' => 'some@email.com',
  'password' => 'somepassword'
];
$newUser = User::create($userData);
```

You'll also need your password hashed in order for it to work with Laravel's authorization. Add the following to your user model - it will hash password before it's saved to the database:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
{
  $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($password);
}
```

Comment: Actually what about the password hash, when creating a user this way the password isn't hashed in the database how can I replicate this functionality? Or better pass it through the same route that it goes thought on a normal registration as to not segment the procedure into two places.

Comment: @DaleSnowdon If you generate a random password and store it with `hash` in database. How can you retrieve the original password later? Without the original password how can the user login?

Comment: to store the password use  Hash::make()

Comment: @smartrahat I never want to be able to see the users password from a security perspective. The user can still log in because, when they submit their original_password it is hashed to hashed_password and then compared to the hashed_password stored in the database. Just make sure you use the same encryption algorithm and any IVs(Initialization vectors). Note about IVs: each user should have its unique IV then if two users have the same password it doesn't show up as such in the database. Luckily i'm using Laravel framework which handles all that for me !!!!

Comment: @DaleSnowdon You said it was a random password. So, I thought it will be randomize by PHP with `rand()` function then store in hash value and nobody will have any information of the unhashed password.